# Error when trying to install Steam on 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, steam

I just started using Ubuntu and am trying to install Steam, but I get the error messsage

> you are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
>   libc.so.6

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

Do those commands:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then install libc

```
sudo apt-get install libc-bin:i386
```

Comment: I'm on the last line and I get a warning that libc-bin will be removed. Am I still on the right track?

Comment: press enter and  complete

Comment: Error occurred 'BrokenCount>0' also says package system is broken :/

Comment: run the command `sudo apt-get install -f ` this will correct the borken

Comment: now it says this...... Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Comment: I got it working.  Used this [http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1266104&page=2&p=11767830#post11767830]

Comment: Then put this in terminal `sudo apt-get install -y steam` found here [http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2233005] seems to work now

Comment: Happy to solve our problem